# Incorporating a dichotomous failure model for sustainment analysis

Tags: systems-engineering, data, failure-analysis

Disclaimer: I am a data scientist, not an engineer.

I have been tasked with forecasting failures of a given part and seeing how it affects inventory. Suppose I have historical yearly failure data for part A. That is, I have a count of how many times part A failed by year (100 failures in 2015, 200 failures in 2016, etc...). Paired with the historical failure numbers are the amount of part A currently in service, that is, how much of part A is currently being used in the "system". The number of failures are dependent on how many parts are in service. If we observe a change in in service numbers, then we expect to see a change in failure numbers as well. When a part fails, we assume a one to one depletion of inventory. That is, one failure will decrease inventory by one.

The problem now is to use this historical failure data to construct a model and to forecast future demand. Where the trouble lies is that when we replace a part from a failure, it may no longer follow the failure trend of historical demand. Therefore, we create a dichotomous model that captures the total number of new parts in service and the number of old parts in service. However, I am having trouble attempting to incorporate the different ratios of old to new parts in service.

Currently, I have fitted a simple linear regression line to the historical data, and then use the line to forecast future demand. This is not ideal as the historical demand is not necessarily linear, but it is a starting point. Now, the challenge is to somehow modify the predictions to include new parts that have been introduced to replace failed parts. My current attempt is to weight the slope and intercept by the proportion of old to new parts in service, as well as "jumping back in time" on the slope line for new parts. In other words, end year inventory may be calculated as:
$$y_i = [(m\cdot r_i)x_{\text{old}} + b\cdot r_i] + [(m\cdot r'_i)x_{\text{new}}+b\cdot r'_i]$$
where $y_i$ is the year end inventory, $m$ is the slope of the regression line, $b$ is the intercept of the regression line, $r_i$ is the proportion of old parts in service, and $r'_i$ is the proportion of new parts in service. However, I constructed this rather heuristically and I am not sure if it is even useful to construct such a model. I am seeking advice on how to handle the dynamic in service numbers to create an accurate model to forecast the failures.

Comment: Perhaps better on the Cross Validated Stack.

Comment: Interesting question. One observation, which probably won't help simplify your life at all, is that for some failure modes, fail rates are distributed in a way that depends heavily on batches (or age-cohorts or rev levels) of parts, including being completely absent in some batches of parts. This comes up time and time again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modeling future behavior using past behavior is fraught with pitfalls. This is why we test large numbers of parts before turning the factory on and stocking the product in the warehouse. That said...

In failure analysis, that dichotomy is called *bimodality* which reflects the fact that there are not one but *two* different possible failure modes that the parts can experience, and those modes represent two different *populations* within the main population.

Statisticians have to deal with this all the time, and a standard text on *descriptive statistics* will outline the correct methodology for you. The key point #1 is to prepare a graph called a *weibull plot* on which the cumulative failure rate for a given failure mode shows up as the slope of a line. Then, you note that different failure modes have differing *slopes* in that plot, and their effects on reliability can be assessed.

Key point #2 is to always be aware that several part populations can be randomly mixed into your inventory, which makes accurate *failure analysis* essential.

Comment: Thank you for the answer niels. I have a question about your answer. From my understanding, it seems to suggest incorporating data driven analysis with theoretical analysis. Deducing the cumulative failure rate for new parts cannot be based on historical data as there is no historical data to begin with. Therefore, is it correct to say that a cumulative failure rate deduced from historical data for the old parts and a theoretical failure rate from the new parts are combined to make future predictions?

Comment: will edit my answer- NN